# Select column not on a group by statement

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, max

So, I have a table called RACES in which I have the following columns

`raceid | year | round`

I want to get the `raceid` for the last race of each year, which would have the highest value in the round column for each year. So I've done the following query:

```
SELECT
    year,
    max(round)
FROM races
group by year
order by year;
```

The result is:

```
year    max(round)
1950    7
1951    8
1952    8
1953    9
1954    9
```

Now if I do

```
SELECT * FROM RACES WHERE YEAR = 1950;
```

I get this:

```
raceid  year    round
833     1950    1
834     1950    2
835     1950    3
836     1950    4
837     1950    5
838     1950    6
839     1950    7
```

Since the number of rounds are variable with time, 1951 might not have 7 rounds but 10. So I want always to get the max value of rounds for a specific year and then print it along with the corresponding `raceid` of that round. In this case it would be **839**

Since `raceid` is not in the group by, I can't select it in the first query. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you also specify the expected result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select year, max(round) as max_round, 
       max(raceid) keep (dense_rank last order by round) as raceid
from   races
group  by year
order  by year
;
```

Documentation for `first` and `last` function:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions074.htm#SQLRF00641

Answer (score 0):

With sample data you posted, that's just another MAX function call:

```
SQL> with races (raceid, year, round) as
  2    (select 700, 1940, 1 from dual union all
  3     select 701, 1940, 2 from dual union all
  4     --
  5     select 833, 1950, 1 from dual union all
  6     select 838, 1950, 6 from dual union all
  7     select 839, 1950, 7 from dual
  8    )
  9  select year,
 10        max(round) max_round,
 11        max(raceid) max_raceid
 12  from races
 13  group by year;

      YEAR  MAX_ROUND MAX_RACEID
---------- ---------- ----------
      1940          2        701
      1950          7        839

SQL>
```

---

However, if `RACEID` isn't `MAX` along with `ROUND`, then you could use your current query as a subquery (or a CTE) and join it with the "original" table:

```
SQL> with races (raceid, year, round) as
  2    (select 700, 1940, 1 from dual union all
  3     select 701, 1940, 2 from dual union all
  4     --
  5     select 900, 1950, 1 from dual union all  --> 900 is MAX for year 1950
  6     select 838, 1950, 6 from dual union all
  7     select 839, 1950, 7 from dual
  8    ),
  9  mrid as
 10    (select year,
 11            max(round) max_round
 12     from races
 13     group by year
 14    )
 15  select m.year,
 16         m.max_round,
 17         r.raceid
 18  from mrid m join races r on r.year = m.year and r.round = m.max_round;

      YEAR  MAX_ROUND     RACEID
---------- ---------- ----------
      1940          2        701
      1950          7        839

SQL>
```

Comment: Since I already have my data in the races table, could I do that without the need to pass those values with te WITH fucntion?

Comment: @BrenoJones - WITH is a "clause" in the query (not a "function"). In cases like Littlefoot used here, we often put the test data in the WITH clause, as a subquery, so we don't need to create an actual table in our databases. The WITH clause is not part of the answer - it's there just for convenience, so the query can be tested ad hoc. Remove it, and use the actual table and column names in the rest of the query.